# Automatically reconnecting clients to Windows VPN on disconnect

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have small number of remote users that will be accessing the company VPN over broad band aircard. I need these user's laptops to connect to the VPN any time it is able to. I also need it to reconnect on the event of a disconnect.

The remote users will be using laptops with Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 has *VPN Reconnect* (actual feature name) which will accomplish exactly what you describe.  Furthermore, Microsoft has a very detailed, step-by-step guide on how to deploy the feature [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20277).